# Easy way to fill progressive data column in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am preparing monthly report of my institution. For example:

**For April**

| Vaccine name | during the month utilization | progressive utilization |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HSV | 500 | 500 |
| BQV | 300 | 300 |
| ASV | 200 | 200 |

**For May**

| Vaccine name | during the month utilization | progressive utilization |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HSV | 600 | 1100 |
| BQV | 200 | 500 |
| ASV | 200 | 400 |

What I did every time:

- I prepared the April sheet and in April during the month and
  progressive total are the same, so no problem.
- While preparing the May sheet, in progressive column I used the formula `=value of current month cell + value of progressive total of previous month`. It's a tedious process.

My question is:
Is there a simple solution to get the progressive total as such by simply putting value in the current sheet or is there a way to create a master excel sheet, where we can put he current month value and get the result?

Comment: The April and May is sheet name?

Comment: I suggest you enter your original data on a single workssheet in a single Table, 
where date is the last day of the month.  Then you can easily use formulas or Power Query to generate the relevant monthly report.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice here is to separate your data entry sheet (left side of screenshot) from the reporting one (right side).

In one worksheet you can just keep entering new data every month.

Setting up reporting sheet:

- G1 is currently uses a formula (`=MAX(Table1[month])`) with number format "MMMM" to show latest month, you can also set it fixed and create separate sheet for each month
- formula for vaccine names: `=UNIQUE(Table1[Vaccine name])`
- formula for monthly amount: `=FILTER(Table1[during the month utilization],(Table1[Vaccine name]=F4)*(Table1[month]=$G$1))`
- formula for running total: `=SUMIF(Table1[Vaccine name],F4,Table1[during the month utilization])`

[image]